# How to properly execute performFetchWithCompletionHandler with multiple blocks inside

Tags: objective-c

I'm using the background fetch method `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` in order to update some user data. However, those processes are fairly complicated and include block statements, so they don't execute synchronously.

My concern is that I am always returning `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);`

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Start background data fetch");

    // Update data -- this method contains various blocks inside
    [GETDataRequest updateUserDataWithUser: user];

    // Update images -- this method contains various blocks inside
    [GETImagesRequest updateUserImagesWithUser: user];

    NSLog(@"Background Data Fetch completed");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414317/when-to-call-completionhandler-in-applicationperformfetchwithcompletionhandler), in regards to `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData)` the following was mentioned:

> You have to call this to let iOS know what the result of your background fetch was. It uses this information to schedule future background fetches. If you neglect to do this, future background fetches may be delayed by the OS. The consequences of not calling this handler might include terminating your app altogether.

As you can see here, I am always saying it's successful whether or not it actually is. The answerer had this to say about my situation:

> ...you should call the completion handler only when your fetch is actually complete. Otherwise iOS will probably put your application back to sleep before the connection completes, and apps shouldn't actually be able to determine UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData versus UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData or UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed until then anyway. How do you know your connection will succeed?

Is what I'm doing ACTUALLY a problem? Will it actually cut off the updates? If it is going to produce unexpected results, what's the solution to this mess? The answer to the question I mentioned wasn't clear enough to me. I have tried using block variables to make it function as it should, but have been unsuccessful. Much appreciated.

Comment: "you should call the completion handler only when your fetch is actually complete" That's totally wrong. Just the opposite. If you don't call it back and call it back quickly, you will never get a background fetch opportunity again; the system will "blackball" you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is meant for Background Fetch Refresh functionality, through this you can make a quick refresh to your app when its in background by mentioning the system time interval to minimum. This service is available in the delegate method performFetchWithCompletionHandler and it will last for 30 seconds. You need to manage your code accordingly to get updated result and then at end as per your result you need to call the appropriate completion handler block.
If you have the long running background task I will prefer then to use Background Fetch Services using NSURLSessions.